How do I escape a comma when using Test-Path with the AD:\ provider
I have a script using Test-Path with the AD: drive to check if a list of Active Directory OUs exist. Several of the OUs have commas in the distinguishedName.
When I lookup distinguishedName values for these items, I see the commas are escaped with '\' characters in the traditional manner.  This DN works with Get-ADOrganizationalUnit but it throws errors with Test-Path AD:\ + distinguishedName
e.g: OU=Soz, Eggs and Chips,DC=BobsCafe,DC=co,DC=uk1
I can get the OU attributes like this:
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit "OU=Soz\, Eggs and Chips,DC=BobsCafe,DC=co,DC=uk"

But if I try this:
Test-Path "AD:\OU=Soz\, Eggs and Chips,DC=BobsCafe,DC=co,DC=uk"

it throws this error (three times!) and returns True:
Test-Path : The object name has bad syntax
At line:1 char:1
+ Test-Path "AD:\OU=Soz\, Eggs and Chips,DC=BobsCafe,DC=co,DC=uk
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (\\RootDSE\OU=So...afe,DC=co,DC=uk:String) [Test-Path], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ADProvider:ItemExists::ADError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand

I also tried this:
Test-Path 'AD:\OU=Soz, Eggs and Chips,DC=BobsCafe,DC=co,DC=uk'

There are no errors but it returns False, even though the OU exists.
These three attempts also all had the same result:
Test-Path 'AD:\OU=Soz`, Eggs and Chips,DC=BobsCafe,DC=co,DC=uk'

Test-Path 'AD:\OU=Soz`2C Eggs and Chips,DC=BobsCafe,DC=co,DC=uk'

Test-Path 'AD:\OU=Soz\2C Eggs and Chips,DC=BobsCafe,DC=co,DC=uk'

How can I do this?

Can you use Get-ADOrganizationalUnit to do the job of Test-Path? Also, can you Set-Location to the OU?

Does ` do the job?

You should use the AD Module for this instead of depending on unknown intricacies of the AD Provider. If you don't / can't use the AD Module you can still use adsi to test if an OU exist and has no dependencies.

@JoelCoehoorn I could but since I want to use it in a one-liner, only very clumsily.

@SantiagoSquarzon The AD: PSDrive provider is part of the ActiveDirectory module.

@MonsieurMerso If that's a backtick, that was my second example

You could probably just use DirectoryEntry.Exists instead of relying on unexpected behavior from the AD Provider, but you should be aware certain characters have to be escaped with \, see reference from Distinguished Names. So a tiny function like this might do the trick:
function Test-ADPath {
    param([Parameter(Mandatory)] [string] $Path)

    [adsi]::Exists('LDAP://RootDSE/' + $Path)
}

Test-ADPath 'OU=Soz\,\ Eggs\ and\ Chips,DC=BobsCafe,DC=co,DC=uk'


You should use the ActiveDirectory PowerShell modules. If you have Microsoft Remote Server Administration Tools installed on your computer, the necessary PowerShell module is installed too. You can check whether you have it by entering this: Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name ActiveDirectory in PowerShell.
If you don't have it installed (if you manage an AD, then you really should though), you can just get the two DLL-s from a a computer that does, and that allows you to use AD PowerShell commands without anything installed.
With the AD PowerShell module installed, verifying whether an OU exists is as simple as:
$ouexist = $true
try
{
    Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity 'DC=fully,DC=qualified,DC=domain'
}
catch
{
    $ouexist = $false
}


I am using the ActiveDirectory powershell module.  The AD: drive comes from the ActiveDirectory module.  Run these commands in your PowerShell session and see what I mean: Get-PSDrive Import-Module ActiveDirectory Get-PSDrive and compare the list before and after.  The run this command:  Get-PSDrive AD |Format-List -Property * to see where the provider is located.

@user2871239 If you use the ActiveDirectory module then why bother with Test-Path instead of the AD module provided tool for searching in the ActiveDirectory? Get-ADOrganizationalUnit doesn't care about commas, spaces, semicolons. and doesn't need even an escape character. If the OU exists, it finds it. Test-Path may not need a try-catch block, but in this case it doesn't work as it should it either.

I know where you're coming from.  I could do that and sometimes I might.  But sometimes I'm teaching others and I want the solution to be clean because PowerShell is capable of that.  It's in a one-liner and Test-Path is elegant whereas wrapping a try-catch  around Get-ADOrganizationlUnit is ugly, harder to read, and easier to duck up.
